# Where is the stolen baby Rattle?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm looking for the stolen baby rattle, last seen in the company of a bird in Skyloft. Where might it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the floating island above the waterfall. If you use the Gust Bellows there in the bird's nest, you should find it.

Comment: I should point out that the bird's nest is on top of the windmill above Kukiel's house, near the bazaar.